Docker Compose Not Passing Build Arguments from .env File
I'm struggling to pass build arguments to my Dockerfile using Docker Compose. Here's a breakdown of my setup:
/sampleDockerProject
│
├── compose/
│ └── Dockerfile
│
├── docker-compose.yml
│
└── .myenvs

.myenvs:
MYENV=testmyenv

Dockerfile:
FROM docker.io/python:3.10.15-slim-bookworm AS python

FROM python AS python-build-stage

ARG MYENV

ENV MYENV_=$MYENV
RUN if [ -z "$MYENV_" ]; then echo 'MYENV_ must be specified.'; exit 1; fi

docker-compose.local.yml:
services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/Dockerfile
      args:
        MYENV: ${MYENV}
    image: env_test_image
    container_name: env_test_image
    env_file:
      - path: .myenvs
        required: true

According to the documentation, this setup should work. However, when I run:
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build

it fails:
WARN[0000] The "MYENV" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Building 0.8s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 179B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [django internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                                                       0.4s
 => [django internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [django 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest@sha256:0a301600e451618e1c0a94c28b5d83f875f6f3c07820a71d6dd2565a000f7408                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [django 2/2] RUN if [ -z "" ]; then echo 'MYENV_ must be specified.'; exit 1; fi                                                                                                                    0.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 > [django 2/2] RUN if [ -z "" ]; then echo 'MYENV_ must be specified.'; exit 1; fi:
0.190 MYENV_ must be specified.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -z \"$MYENV_\" ]; then echo 'MYENV_ must be specified.'; exit 1; fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Alternatively, using --env-file from the command line works perfectly:
docker compose --env-file .myenvs -f docker-compose.yml build

[+] Building 0.4s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 179B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [django internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [django internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [django 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest@sha256:0a301600e451618e1c0a94c28b5d83f875f6f3c07820a71d6dd2565a000f7408                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [django 2/2] RUN if [ -z "testmyenv" ]; then echo 'MYENV_ must be specified.'; exit 1; fi                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [django] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:df00a7c6e5a03750270827e15047c859d8b8bc7d56e6e3355d209cb69b72272a                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/env_test_image                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [django] resolving provenance for metadata file

What is causing the environment variables to be ignored in my docker-compose.yml file?

Please provide a [mcve], not just excerpts which may or may not be representative. Odds are that you find the mistake yourself while doing so, which is also why this is required.

I edited my question and inserted a minimal example.

The env_file in the dockercompose.yml is (as far as I understand it) only for the running container and not used during the build phase, thus ${MYENV} will not be known when parsing and handling the dockercompose.yml (especially when building the image). But when you pass with --env-file the .myenv file is parsed before and thus the variables are also known in the build phase

There are a couple of places environment variables come from and a couple of places they go to.  In the linked question, I've included a more detailed explanation of what's happening and what specifically needs to be done (and why you need docker-compose --env-file here).
